# How to call actual callback function in Jest unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, callback

I have the following piece of code.

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  process("postProcess");
  window.clearTimeout();
});
```

When I write unit test to this, I can assert requestAnimationFrame getting called but not on the process function and clearTimeout since requestAnimationFrame is jest.fn(). How to call the actual callback function while unitTesting?

Comment: if you want to call the actual call, why do you mock it using `jest.fn()`?

Answer (score 3):

You've commented that you are able to mock requestAnimationFrame already and can assert that it is called. This actually gets you a long way to an answer.

Extend your jest mock from the `jest.fn()` to an implementation that immediately calls the callback that is passed to it as an argument.

```
requestAnimationFrame.mockImplementation((callback) => callback())
```

Thus when your tests run `process` and `window.clearTimeout` will be immediately invoked; so long as you are also mocking or spying on those functions you can assert that those are called too.

Comment: Changing it this, requestAnimationFrame: jest.fn().mockImplementation(callback => callback()), did not work

Comment: Did you mock the methods inside the callback?

Comment: yes I did requestAnimationFrame: jest.fn().mockImplementation(fn)

const fn = () => {
process("postProcess");
  window.clearTimeout();}